# Retrieving order information from square register over wirless network

Tags: square-connect

I am using square register to take orders and process payments, and would like to get the order details once a payment is complete / order is saved.  I know this can be done through the Connect API, but don't want to rely on internet access and would like an immediate and reliable result (webhooks can take up to 60 seconds).

It seems like this is possible because there are apps such as Fresh KDS that are communicating simply by being on the same wireless network, but do not require internet access, so they aren't hitting the API, but I can't seem to find anywhere in the documentation where this is possible.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Square doesn't support retrieving order details from Square Registers on the same wireless network yet.